# How to disable file extension check during incoming file transfers?

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer

I'm running CyanogenMod 10 on my Nexus 7. As with all other Android devices, for some reason Google thought it cute to check file extensions of incoming Bluetooth file transfers and reject them if they're not one of a handful of extensions.

In other words, a file called file.pem, file.xxx will not transfer via Bluetooth but file.zip or file.jpg will.

Is there something I can do on my rooted device to disable this silly file extension check?

Comment: No, you cannot do anything about it as that is integrated into the actual framework, where there is a list of filters based on filename and extensions.

Comment: Can change the extension to jpg or some common extension and then transfer

Answer (score 1):

You could use a workaround, compress your file as zip archive and then extract it on your Android Device.

I use [AndroZip](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agilesoftresource&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmFnaWxlc29mdHJlc291cmNlIl0.) for it. As an alternative you could use a better Variant. [Total Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5naGlzbGVyLmFuZHJvaWQuVG90YWxDb21tYW5kZXIiXQ..).